# minimum of a function predicted by 2nd-degree polynomial regression

Tags: r, regression

I have a to fit curves to my data using a linear model with polynomial of 2nd degree, for example :

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(0,1,2,3,4,5), y=c(0, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26))
lm1 <- lm(y~x+I(x^2), data=data)
plot(y~x, data=data)
points(predict(lm1)~data$x, type="l", col="blue", lwd=1)
```

then I would like to find the minimum of the function predicted by the model. I can extract the coefficient to write the function

```
a<-summary(lm1)$coef[,1][1]
b<-summary(lm1)$coef[,1][2]
c<-summary(lm1)$coef[,1][3]
```

But after that I don't know how to do and didn't find an answer on Google. Isn't it a function in R that calculates that ? Or should I calculate the zero of the derivative ?

Comment: yes, go ahead and calculate the zero of the derivative.  It's an easy calculation.

Comment: I beginn with R and I don't find it's so easy to calculate derivative with the coefficients extracted from lm summary. So if you can give me a more explicite answer, I would be very grateful !

Comment: if `y=a+b*x+c*x^2` then `y' = b + 2*c*x`; `b+2*c*x=0` when `x=-b/(2*c)`.  Then the `y` value is `a-b^2/(2*c)+b^2/(4*c)` (you should check my algebra and simplify the result).  Or google "minimum of a parabola" ...

Comment: yes thank you I know these formulae but I need to automate this on R in order to have one script that I can run on many datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up data and fit model:

```
dd <- data.frame(x=c(0,1,2,3,4,5), 
                 y=c(0, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26))
lm1 <- lm(y~x+I(x^2), data=dd)
```

Get predictions:

```
pp <- data.frame(x=seq(-3,5,length=51))
pp$y <- predict(lm1,newdata=pp)
```

Function to return minimum x/y values:

```
getMin <- function(model) {
    cc <- setNames(as.list(coef(model)),c("a","b","c"))
    with(cc,
         c(x=-b/(2*c),y=a-b^2/(4*c)))
}
mm <- getMin(lm1)
```

Plot the results:

```
plot(y~x,data=dd,xlim=c(-3,5))
with(pp,lines(x,y,col=4))
points(mm[1],mm[2],pch=16,col=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Meanwhile I also found the "optimize" function that could be helpful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try something like :

```
 predict(lm1, interval="prediction")[, "lwr"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! min(predict(lm1, interval="prediction")[, "lwr"]) gives me the minimal y-value, right ? And what if I want the associated x-value too ?

Comment: Your fitted values of x correspond to the predicted values.  If you want to provide new values of x, add those to newdata in predict.lm

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants.